# Counting UITableView ContentView height is not always correct

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a messenger app, which displays a dialog between two people.
Parsing API response, I got text for inbox and outbox messages. Then I create a cell, using a `UITableViewCell` prototype from the storyboard.
All constraints are adjusted correctly.

[image: Outer constraints]

[image: Inner constraints]

The problem is that I use

```
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

to scroll the `tableView` to the bottom to have the last message in focus but the `contentView` of the upper cells is not counted at this time.

So i had to count height of cell before it is displayed. For this i use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RJMessageCell *cell = [self configureBasicCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, UILayoutFittingCompressedSize.height);
    CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:maximumSize].height;
    return height;
}    

- (RJMessageCell *)configureBasicCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *inboxIdentifier = @"Inbox";
    static NSString *outboxIdentifier = @"Outbox";

    NSString *identifier;

    RJMessage *message = [[[self.messageSectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] messages] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (message.messageIsMine) {
        identifier = outboxIdentifier;
    } else {
        identifier = inboxIdentifier;
    }


    RJMessageCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    cell.messageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.f;
    cell.messageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    if ([message.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        cell.messageTextLabel.text = @" ";
    } else {
        cell.messageTextLabel.text = message.text;
    }
    cell.messageTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.messageTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    cell.timeLabel.text = [self stringTimeFromTimeInterval:message.messageInterval];

    if (message.messageState == RJMessageStateUnread) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:151/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:0.4];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Also the UILabel on screenshots are custom, to setBounds to label

```
- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    [super setBounds:bounds];

    if (self.numberOfLines == 0 && bounds.size.width != self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth) {
        self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width;
        [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }
}
```

And the last thing i do, adding **estimatedRowHeight** in **viewDidLoad**

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

The first time they appear everything looks good, but when I scroll the table up and down, my cells change their size randomly.

[image: When i scroll up]

[image: And when i scroll down]

What's wrong with the cell height?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return Height by calculating the text width & height which you want to place inside the cell.

```
//Height For Row at index path
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDataSource[indexPath.row]]];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];

    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:cellText
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName: cellFont
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.size.width - 90.0, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    return rect.size.height + 42;
}
```